# Data scraping with wget and regex

Tags: bash, grep, wget

i'm just learning bash scripting, i was trying to scrape some data out of a site, mostly wikitionary. This is what I'm trying on the command line right now but it is not returning any result

```
wget -qO- http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/robust | egrep '<ol>{[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*}*</ol>'
```

What i'm trying is to get the data between the  tags, just want them to be displayed. Can you please help me find out what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Regex's are not fit for HTML parsing or any form of scraping. Have a look at Python's BeautifulSoup and Mechanize library, plenty of examples can be seen on scraperwiki, e.g. https://scraperwiki.com/scrapers/galway-arts-council/edit/

Comment: Also, does egrep really use `{}` for grouping? That would be a very unusual choice. Do you really only want to extract things with no spaces, just letters and digits? And why `([a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*)*` instead of the equivalent `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to send output to stdout:

```
wget -q http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/robust -q -O - | ...
```

to get all `<ol>` tags with grep you can do:

```
wget -q http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/robust -O - | tr '\n' ' ' | grep -o '<ol>.*</ol>'
```

Comment: your edit worked, thanks but it is displaying the <ol> tag too and also how do i get each output on a new line !?

Comment: to can pipe it via `| sed 's/<ol>/\n<ol>/g'` for example.

Answer (score 2):

At least you need to

- activate regular expressions by adding the `-e` switch.
- send output from wget to stdout instead of to disk by adding the `-O -` option

Honestly, I'd say grep is the wrong tool for this task, since grep works on a per-line basis, and your expression stretches over several lines.

I think `sed` or `awk` would be a better fit for this task.

With `sed` it would look like

```
wget -O - -q http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/robust | sed -n "/<ol>/,/<\/ol>/p"
```

If you want to get rid of the extra `<ol>` and `</ol>` you could do append

```
... | grep -v -E "</?ol>"
```

**Related links**

- https://superuser.com/questions/165634/grep-multiline-pattern
- http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/56703-multiline-grep.html

Comment: hi sorry i used egrep as well, copied the wrong code here. i used egrep on my terminal. Updating question

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly then the goal is to extract the visible text content from within ol-sections. I would do it this way:

```
wget -qO- http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/robust | 
  hxnormalize -x | 
  hxselect "ol" | 
  lynx -stdin -dump -nolist
```

[source: ["Using the Linux Shell for Web Scraping"]](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/using-linux-shell-web-scraping/)

hxnormalize preprocesses the HTML code for hxselect which applies the CSS selector "ol". Lynx will render the code and reduce it to what is visible in a browser.